# Multiple classes just select the one clicked

Tags: jquery

Jquery Code:

```
$(".tog").toggle(
function() {
    $(".tog span").removeClass('stog');
    $(".tog span").addClass('stogm');
    $(this).next().slideDown('fast');
},
function() {
    $(".tog span").removeClass('stogm');
    $(".tog span").addClass('stog');
    $(this).next().slideUp('fast');
}
);
```

I have few `side_cat_toggle` classes, but i want the one i clicked only to take the changes above. Currently every classes of `side_cat_toggle` is changing and not the one i clicked.

How do i do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".tog").toggle(
function() {
    $("span", this).removeClass('stog').addClass("stogm");
    $(this).next().slideDown("fast");
},
function() {
    $("span", this).addClass('stog').removeClass("stogm");
    $(this).next().slideUp("fast");
}
);
```

Comment: Hi marko, can you explain what does `this` property does on `$("span", this)` ? i thought `this` same as the above .tog?

Comment: Hi @cicakman sorry for the late reply. The 2nd argument is "context" for the selector which means it will only search for `span` elements under the `.tog` that was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".tog").click(
    var $that = $this;
    $this.toggle(... $that ... ));
```

Use $that to access $(".tog")

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".tog").click(function() {

    $(this).find('span').removeClass('stog').addClass('stogm');

    $(this).toggle(
        function() {
            $(this).next().slideDown('fast');
        },
        function() {
            $(this).next().slideUp('fast');
        }
    );
});
```